# How an yaksha roopa of bagavathi devi looks like?

Tags: devi-bhagavata-purana

Sri Bhagavathi devi appeared as yaksha roopa at devas and Indira as per 8.82 of 12th skandha or chapter (chapter name: parashakthi mahima) of sri Devi Bhagavatha purana.  Can any body explain how this yaksha roopa of sri-devi looks like?.